# How to divide an array more than once based on index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass an index to a function, and based on that index I want to divide the array, into multi dimensional arrays.

Here's my code

```
const [splittedPdfs, setSplittedPdfs] = useState([1,2,3,4,5,6])

const handleButtonClick = () => {

//perform the logic over here

}
```

Just for reference purpose I am declaring the initial state, but in my app the initial state is dynamic and it gets updated before the `handleButtonClick` function is called, so no issues over there.

I have a button in which when I click, I am calling this function while passing the index.

```
<button onClick={() => handleButtonClick(index)}>Button</button>
```

Now what I need is, when index is passed as `2`, then my state should get updated to `[[1,2],[3,4,5]]`, I am easily able to achieve this but am unable to figure out how to proceed with the next step.

Now when I again call the function while passing the index as 4, then the updated state should be this `[[1,2],[3,4],[5]`

Can someone help me achieve this?

Note: The initial array can be between any range, it's not limited to 1-5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no nested array more than once, we don't have to use recursive functions (which I already don't like to use, because it uses too much memory).

Also this questions is all about Javascript, so the below algorithm is in Javascript. You'll need to tweak it a little for ReactJS.

Algorithm;

1 - First, check if **all the elements** in the main array are **NOT** an array. If that's the case, just slice it.

2- Then, if any of the elements are is an array, loop over that sub array.
If the index is equal to the sub array's element, slice it, save it into a dummy array.

3- Hold a flag, when the above condition is true, change this flag to false, so when you push the other sub arrays which does not includes your "index", you push this element to the dummy array.

4 - Then set dummy array to the original array.

Since you're doing this in ReactJS, you have to change `myArr = dummyArr` parts to `setSplittedPdfs(dummyArr)`.

**Inputs**;

```
const result = divideArr(4, myArr);

const result2 = divideArr(2, myArr);

const result3 = divideArr(2, myArr);
```

**Outputs**:

```
Original array: [1,2,3,4,5]
myarr1 :  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5 ] ] // index = 4
myarr2 :  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5 ] ] // index = 2
myarr3 :  [ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5 ] ] // again index = 2
```

---

```
let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let flag = false;

function divideArr(index, arr) {
  let dummyArr = [];

  if (arr.every((item) => !Array.isArray(item))) {
    const first = arr.slice(0, index);
    const second = arr.slice(index, arr.length);
    dummyArr.push(first);
    dummyArr.push(second);
    myArr = dummyArr;
  } else {
    for (let ind = 0; ind < arr.length; ind++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < arr[ind].length; y++) {
        flag = true;
        if (arr[ind][y] === index) {
          if (arr[ind].length > 2) {
            const first = arr[ind].slice(0, index);
            const second = arr[ind].slice(index, arr[ind].length);
            dummyArr.push(first);
            dummyArr.push(second);
            myArr = dummyArr;
          } else {
            dummyArr.push([arr[ind][0]]);
            dummyArr.push([arr[ind][1]]);
            myArr = dummyArr;
          }

          flag = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (flag) dummyArr.push(arr[ind]);
    }
  }
}
```